# Aligning text and preserving img aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to  arrange a header layout like the one on the image[image]

I'd like the background image to keep the aspect ratio for every screen size and the text floating left at the bottom with some margin. I have the following below, but the problem is that text goes below the image at some breakpoints or too close to the bottom

CSS

```
.header {
  background-size:100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:100%;
  color: $dark;
  .summary{
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:30%;
    margin-bottom:5%;
    margin-left:triple($spacing-unit);
    hr {
      position: relative;
      height:6px;
      background: $green;
      text-align:left;
      border-width: 6px !important;
      width: 130px;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<section id="main" class="no-pad">
    <div class='header' style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1280x756')">
      <div class="summary">
        <hr></hr>
        <p class="tagline">BIG TEXT HERE</p>
        <p class="tagline">Smaller text</p>
        <p class="intro">continuing smaller text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Sound to me like it's the background image that is most likely not working as intended. Try `background-size: cover;`

Comment: That actually fixed the issue

Comment: Okay, I'll add as answer. If you could mark it as a working answer I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

via above comment(confirmed as working answer):

The issues sounds to me like it's due to the background image itself not working as intended. Try `background-image: cover`;